# Javascript: Switch text on select

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I have:** Simple block of html text:

```
<p>
The future of manned space exploration and development of space depends critically on the
creation of a dramatically more proficient propulsion architecture for in-space transportation.
A very persuasive reason for investigating the applicability of nuclear power in rockets is the 
vast energy density gain of nuclear fuel when compared to chemical combustion energy...
</p>
```

**Question:** *How to insert a notion BELOW (between existing rows of text) some phrase with help of JavaScript?*

**I.e.** I want to explain in a few words what is `nuclear power` at the text above, so I want to insert a few words below that phrase (say on mouse over).

Comment: Does it have to pure JavaScript? Why can't you mark up the phrase in the HTML?

Comment: @RoToRa because I want to do that dynamically on some events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it. Please let me know if you need more details.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<p>
The future of manned space exploration and development of space depends critically on the
creation of a dramatically more proficient propulsion architecture for in-space transportation.
A very persuasive reason for investigating the applicability of nuclear power in rockets is the 
vast energy density gain of nuclear fuel when compared to chemical combustion energy...
</p>
<script>

var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
p = p[0];
var tmp = '';
p.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    tmp = p.innerHTML;
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML + ' ...about nuclear...';
}, false);

p.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    p.innerHTML = tmp;
}, false);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's a version with a generic function you can use for any element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>

var switchText = function(element, text){
    var tmp = '';
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        tmp = element.innerHTML;
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + text;
    }, false);

    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
        element.innerHTML = tmp;
    }, false);
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>
The future of manned space exploration and development of space depends critically on the
creation of a dramatically more proficient propulsion architecture for in-space transportation.
A very persuasive reason for investigating the applicability of nuclear power in rockets is the 
vast energy density gain of nuclear fuel when compared to chemical combustion energy...
</p>
<script>

var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
switchText(p[0], '...about nuclear...');

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

To insert it right next to a word. I used span tags with red color for emphasis. You can of course add what ever you like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>

var switchText = function(element, words, text){
    var tmp = '';
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        tmp = element.innerHTML;
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(words, function(m){
            return m+'<span class="nuc">'+text+'</span>';

         });
    }, false);

    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
        element.innerHTML = tmp;
    }, false);
};
</script>
<style>
.nuc{ color: red; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>
The future of manned space exploration and development of space depends critically on the
creation of a dramatically more proficient propulsion architecture for in-space transportation.
A very persuasive reason for investigating the applicability of nuclear power in rockets is the 
vast energy density gain of nuclear fuel when compared to chemical combustion energy...
</p>
<script>

var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
switchText(p[0], /nuclear/g, '...about nuclear...');

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I've also added the words parameter to the `switchText` function to make it more generic as well.

The fourth, and final condition is settled. The following will allow text on a specifically hovered word, or phrase.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>

var switchText = function(element, words, text){

    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(words, function(m){
        return '<p class="nuc">'+m+'</p>';


     });

     var nuc = element.getElementsByClassName('nuc');
    for(var i=0; i<nuc.length; i++){
        (function(nuc){
            var tmp = nuc.innerHTML,
                doing = false;
            nuc.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
                if(!doing)
                    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + text;

                doing = true;
            });

            nuc.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
                this.innerHTML = tmp;
                doing = false;
            });
        })(nuc[i]);
   }
};
</script>
<style>
.nuc{ color: red; display: inline;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>
The future of manned space exploration and development of space depends critically on the
creation of a dramatically more proficient propulsion architecture for in-space transportation.
A very persuasive reason for investigating the applicability of nuclear power in rockets is the 
vast energy density gain of nuclear fuel when compared to chemical combustion energy...
</p>
<script>

var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
switchText(p[0], /nuclear/g, '...about nuclear...');

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

As a reminder using this method with certain types of `CSS positioning` one could make `styled popups`, `inline navigation`, and possibly other boxes with strange behavior.

Comment: sorry if I explain the task badly, but I need to inset `... about nuclear ...` text BELOW  the nuclear word. I mean between existing rows of text

Comment: Do you want it inline inside the paragraph?

Comment: suppose I want to do that on user click. The problem is that I want to do that dynamically.

Comment: moreover I want that text be inserted below the seliected one

Comment: I've updated it for a hover. If you really want it to be from selected like when you hightlight text with a mouse drag that's a whole other ball of wax.

Comment: at first I wanted to make a notion below the selected text. But now I realize I really like your idea (about switching). Thanks!